# AngularJs: Iterating over array inside directive in order to create nested set of directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Inside angularJS directive I'm trying to iterate over array and based on values I would like to create nested list of directives.
Current version of directive

**Directive type**

```
    .directive("type", function($compile, $log){
        return{
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                type: '='
            },
            template: "<div></div>",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                if (angular.isArray(scope.type)){
                    angular.forEach(scope.type, function(value, index){
                        $log.error(value);
                        element.append("<type type='scope.type['"+index+"]'></type>");
                    });
                } else if (angular.isObject(scope.type)){
                    element.append("OBJECT")
                } else {
                    element.append("<div>{{scope.type}}</div>")
                }
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
             }
        };
      })
```

I also tried to use above directive with next version of link function:

```
if (angular.isArray(scope.type)) {
    element.append("<div ng-repeat='element in scope.type'><type type='element'></type></div>");
} else if (angular.isObject(scope.type)) {
    element.append("OBJECT")
} else {
    element.append("<div>{{scope.type}}</div>")
}
$compile(element.contents())(scope)
}
```

None of provided codes solve my issue.
Below you will find example explaining on specific case:

> Let's say that I had next object in the `scope.type = [null,"int"]`. Now I would like to use `<type type='type'><type>` and as a result of first evaluation I want to have sth like:
>   `<type type='type[0]'></type><type type='type[1]'></type>`
>   Further evaluation of those values should lead to some simpler form but right now it is not important.

How I can achieve sth like this?

### Edit

I tried even to exctract part of the code responsible for iteration to the seperate directive but it still does not work. Code:

Update link function in type directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (angular.isArray(scope.type)) {
        element.append("<typeb type='scope.type'></typeb>")
    } else if (angular.isObject(scope.type)) {
        element.append("OBJECT")
    } else {
        element.append("<div>{{scope.type}}</div>")
    }
    $compile(element.contents())(scope)
}
```

New directive:

```
.directive("typeb", function($compile, $log){
      return{
          restrict: "E",
          replace: true,
          transclude: true,
          scope: {
              type: '='
          },
          template: "<div ng-repeat='t in type'>{{t}}</div>",
      };
    })
```

Problem still occurs but generated html contains only next pieces as a result of `typeb` directive:
`<!-- ngRepeat: t in type -->`

Comment: try `element.append($compile("<div ng-repeat='element in scope.type'><type type='element'></type></div>")(scope));`

Comment: It does not help me. Interesting thing is that in html I see something like that: `<!-- ngRepeat: el in scope.type -->` in case that `scope.type` is equal to `["double","null"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are getting is `<!-- ngRepeat: t in type -->` this is because your type didn't contains any value, when it is inside `typeb` directive

Your directive shouldn't be use scope.variable on view.
Scope variable will be directly accessible by their name like

`{{type}}` or `<typeb type='type'></typeb>`

Change your link code to below.

**Directive link**

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (angular.isArray(scope.type)) {
        element.append("<typeb type='type'></typeb>")
    } else if (angular.isObject(scope.type)) {
        element.append("OBJECT")
    } else {
        element.append("<div>{{type}}</div>")
    }
    $compile(element.contents())(scope)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ng-repeat in the template

```
<your-directive attr="item.someattr" ng-repeat="item in items"></your-directive>

.directive("type", function($compile, $log){
    return{
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        template: "NG REPEAT HERE",
        ...
  })
```

Comment: Where exactly? I am using ng-repeat in link function (second example) but it does not work.

Comment: Updated it. Basically, in the outer scope of where you want your repeated directives. You have this outer directive type, use it's template to ng-repeat the sub directives

Comment: The thing is that value of the attribute passed to the `type` directive it is not always array or object - sometimes it could be just single string like: 'int'. It will tackle such situation?

Comment: Allow your sub directive to deal with it's actual type, displaying itself in the correct way. Separate the repeating behaviour from the type specific display behaviour